# Why do electrons couple in atoms?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, pauli-exclusion-principle, quantum-chemistry, spin-statistics

In describing electron states in hydrogen, we have a very "simple" picture, at least in intro-quantum. But this only has one electron! As we permit more electrons, we also have things like the exclusion principle, which comes from the spin-statistics theorem, but that relies on the electrons having some kind of coupled wave functions, right? Why do electrons always come in pairs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A potential well in the Schrodinger equation will produce energy levels similar to the [energy levels of the hydrogen atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/hyde.html#c3)

A nucleus with two protons to be neutral will need two electrons. These will be accommodated in the lowest two energy levels: because of the spin statistics of electrons they cannot occupy the exact same energy level. A nucleus with three protons (Z=3) will need three electrons occupying the lowest three energy levels [etc](http://www.ptable.com/). The electrons may thermally or by photon interactions be kicked up to higher energy levels giving the characteristic spectral lines of the [specific atom](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/quantum/helium.html) when returning to the ground state.

Electrons do not come in pairs. The fill up the levels so that the atoms are neutral.